# Where should I ask a question about my mobile device?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

I am having an issue with my mobile device (probably OS related) as a normal user. On which site should I post my question?

Comment: Is it a mobile device you hang on a crib or one that comes with a EULA that you've implicitly read by turning it on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's an Android device, then [Android Enthusiasts SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/).

If it's an iOS device, try [Apple SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

There's an Area 51 proposal for [Windows Phone](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone), and another for [Mobile Phones](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11003/mobile-phones).

Do **not** ask on Super User unless the question is somehow about interfacing your mobile device with a "regular" computer.

Comment: What about our WebOS friends? Where do they go? (not that I'm implying there are actually WebOS users in existence... :P)

Comment: No idea, @jrg. I hope someone updates this quite intentionally CW answer with that information.

Comment: @jrg They don't go anywhere, nor do Symbian, Windows Phone 7, Windows Mobile, BlackBerry, etc. users.  Once upon a time there was the Electronic Gadgets site, but no more.